# Оператор присваивания и конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

Хочу разобраться с вызовом конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания в классе.

Правда ли, что здесь вызовется конструктор копирования и только он:

```
SomeClass A = B;
```

А здесь только оператор присваивания:

```
Matrix A, B;
A = B;
```

Если так, то чем отличается конструктор копирования от оператора присваивания, почему нельзя заменить один другим и зачем в С++ они разделены?

Comment: Вы забываете, что в вашем втором примере вызывается сначала конструктор, а потом только оператор присваивания.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Задача *любого* конструктора - создать в сырой неинициализированной памяти объект, которого до этого момента еще не существовало. В общем случае, объект, который "видит" конструктор в начале своей работы, содержит непредсказуемый мусор. Задача конструктора - *проинициализировать* объект, т.е. придать всем его компонентам осмысленные значения.

Оператор присваивания же работает с уже ранее созданным объектом, т.е. с объектом, который уже ранее был полностью сконструирован (каким-то конструктором). Такой объект уже содержит какие-то корректно помещенные в него осмысленные данные. Задача оператора присваивания - заменить эти *старые* осмысленные данные *новыми* осмысленными данными, скопированными из объекта-источника (из правой части оператора присваивания).

Это две совершенно разные задачи.

В общем случае, работа оператора присваивания состоит из двух этапов: корректно убрать из объекта старое содержимое, а затем корректно скопировать в него новое содержимое. Работа же конструктора копирования не имеет первого этапа, ибо никакого старого содержимого в этот момент в объекте нет.

То есть упрощенно можно сказать, что конструктор копирования - это "половинка" оператора присваивания.

Comment: Отличный ответ, большое спасибо! Скажите, а во втором моем примере вызывается ли конструктор копирования или срабатывает только оператор присваивания?

Comment: @John: Во втором примере оба объекта инициализируются *конструкторами по умолчанию* (если таковые есть).  А затем вызывается копирующий оператор присваивания. Конструктор копирования во втором примере не вызывается.